# Do strict types in PHP affect variables?

Tags: php, php-7

I know when using `declare(strict_types=1)` I must pass parameters of given type otherwise an `Exception` is raised, but one question:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function add(int $firstNumber, int $secondNumber)
{
    $firstNumber = "example";

    return $firstNumber . " " . $secondNumber;
}
```

My question is why I'm allowed to change the `$firstNumber`'s type to `string` if `int` was declared?

For instance, in Java, I can't do casting that way. Parameter type `int` must remain `int` otherwise code won't even compile.

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't make variables of strict type but rather the function parameter and return types. It seems variables are still allowed to be loosely typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are strict typing only the input of the function, not the return or any of the variables in the function itself. From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) -

> ***Strict typing applies to function calls*** made from within the file with strict typing enabled, not to the functions declared...

So your call to the function with a non-integer:

```
add('example',2);
```

will return the error you expect -

> Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to add() must be of the type int, string given, called in...

But sending integers to your function will allow the function call to proceed and variables within will be *weakly* typed.